# How to get facebook like total_count using FB Graph API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm coding for integrating the facebook to my app. I want to get the total of the like count of an object, I read the doc at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes
and they said the request is:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                           initWithGraphPath:@"/{object-id}/likes"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                  id result,
                                  NSError *error) {
// Handle the result
}];
```

But what are the params I need to pass?

I did pass the params that's `@{@"fields":@"share"}` then the result returned is

```
"share": {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 0
  }
```

I used the Graph API Explorer with that URL then it returned:

```
 {
  "og_object": {
    "id": "952460714815635",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-08-20T08:45:43+0000",
    "url": "http://dev-vn.magestore.com/simicart/1800/index.php/blackberry-8100-pearl.html/likes"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 0
  },
  "id": "http://dev-vn.magestore.com/simicart/1800/index.php/blackberry-8100-pearl.html/likes"
}
```

But I can't find the count of like for this object. Where is the total_count property they mentioned? Anyone who has the experiences about it, please help me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending `nil` in the `parameters` part. So your request will look like:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                           initWithGraphPath:@"/{object-id}/likes"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                  id result,
                                  NSError *error) {
// Handle the result
}];
```

In the response, you should get a key `total_count` with a corresponding value of total number of likes.

If this doesn't work, please try to send `["summary" = true]` in the `parameters` part and check if you get the required filed in the response. In this case your request should look like:

```
NSDictionary *setFlag = @[@"summary" = true];
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{object-id}/likes"
                                      parameters:setFlag
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
    }];
```

Please try this and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, I added the parameter: @{@"summary":@"true"} but it didn't return total_count value, it was still same like before. :(

Comment: Please search for how to set certain flag in Facebook Graph API request for iOS. The documentation stated that if you set the flag as `summary=true` then you should get the `total_count` in response.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly write the parameters to path. i couldn't test it but it should work.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                           initWithGraphPath:@"/{object-id}/likes?summary=true&fields=total_count"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                  id result,
                                  NSError *error) {
// Handle the result
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, using FBSDKGraphRequest was seem like not work. I used NSURLConnection for requesting directly by the URL and it's worked.

```
 NSString* requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = \"%@\"",productURL];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[requestURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
//send it synchronous
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSDictionary* data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
[productMoreVC stopLoadingData];

if(!error)
{
    lblLikeCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[data objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"like_count"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue on Facebook. I created a ticket about this problem - now it's [fixed](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1086833811373611).

**Request:**

/v2.6/me?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)

**Response:**

```
{
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 7
    }
  },
  "id": "1234567890"
}
```